# Does Go have file name restrictions?

Tags: go, filenames

I created a file with square brackets called `[id].go` but I am unable to build it.

When I run `go build "[id].go"`, I see the the following:

> can't load package: package main: invalid input file name "[id].go"

Are there restrictions on Go file names? Specifically, what is not allowed? Please provide documentation if any.

Comment: Read the language spec. Implementation may restrict package names even further.

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/internal/load/pkg.go#L1826-L1835 *"To be conservative, we reject almost any arg beginning with non-alphanumeric ASCII."* As an example if you try `a[id].go` as the file name you should be good.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks! If you add this as an answer I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the time of writing, Go files must begin with one of the following:

- `0` through `9`
- `a` through `z`
- `A` through `Z`
- `.` (period)
- `_` (underscore)
- `/` (forward slash)
- `>= utf8.RuneSelf` (char 0x80 or higher)
- Two or more files in the same folder can't be named equal (case insensitive match)

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/993ec7f6cdaeb38b88091f42d6369d408dcb894b/src/cmd/go/internal/load/pkg.go#L1826-L1835

> To be conservative, we reject almost any arg beginning with non-alphanumeric ASCII.

As an example if you try `a[id].go` as the file name you should be good to go.