What is the definition of a Go file?
This:
go run .source.go

produces following error:

package command-line-arguments: no Go files in ...

If I remove the initial dot from the file name it works fine.
What is the definition of a "Go file"? Why are hidden Go files files no Go files?
This works also fine:
go run ·source.go


Directory and file names that begin with "." or "_" are ignored
by the go tool, as are directories named "testdata".

@user459872 Reference?

Hidden files are ignored, because that is the convention most people and existing tools expect.

Try go help packages | grep "\".\""

https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Package_lists_and_patterns

@JimB Here someone says that period and underscore are allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60145673/402322

@ceving I've commented on the answer you linked, because it is not correct.

. and _ characters are not valid as the first character of source files in Go packages and will be skipped when that package is imported. The documentation is authoritative:

Directory and file names that begin with "." or "_" are ignored by the go tool, as are directories named "testdata".

If you want to trace where this is actually implemented in the toolchain, see the Import function which is responsible for loading Go packages and is also the source of the no Go files in... error. This is responsible for determining which file(s) in the file system should form a package. The comment describes that the following types of files are skipped when loading the package:
// In the directory containing the package, .go, .c, .h, and .s files are
// considered part of the package except for:
//
//   - .go files in package documentation
//   - files starting with _ or . (likely editor temporary files)
//   - files with build constraints not satisfied by the context


The no Go files error
In case the internal workings of the Go toolchain are of interest, the provenance of the error you see when no source files are present is as follows:
The Import routine returns an error type build.NoGoError.
This is subsequently replaced by a load.NoGoError type in load.(*Package).setLoadPackageDataError. This error type provides friendlier information to the user regarding exactly where the error was, based on the Package information returned by Import; for example, it inspects the Package to provide different error messages in the following cases:

all files are ignored due to build constraints
only Go test files are present, but the command invoked does not care for them

This command does not specifically report that files are skipped in a package import because they start with . characters. This is likely a strategic choice, given the expectation that such files are likely to be temporary files generated by editors, and as such, these warnings would occur often in the common case when using the toolchain despite no issue existing. The Go tool typically follows a careful philosophy to report issues only when they are actionable, meaningful and actually errors, rather than warnings that are likely to be irrelevant.

The SafeArg method
In the comments, you referred to a separate answer describing the SafeArg method.
This method is used to filter command-line arguments to the Go command to determine what is 'safe' as an argument. The constraints imposed by this function are less restrictive than the constraints imposed by the Import routine, as this function must handle many types of argument to the Go toolchain. Furthermore, it permits the first character of an argument to be a . because this ensures that paths to other directories can be passed to commands, such as ./main.go or ../main.go. This is noted in the comments to SafeArg:
// We accept leading . _ and / as likely in file system paths.

